# ngAnimate on ngShow not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to execute a animated menu using ngAnimate.

home.html

```
<div id="left-menu" ng-hide="showMenu">
    <div class="wrapmenu">
      Menu
    </div>

</div>

<div id="content-wrapper" ng-show="showMenu" ng-animate="{show: 'fadeIn', hide:'fadeOut'}">
  <button id="menu" ng-click="showMenu = !showMenu"></button>
</div>
```

Style.css

```
.fadeIn-setup,.fadeOut-setup {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear opacity;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear opacity;
    -o-transition: 1s linear opacity;
    transition: 1s linear opacity;
}
.fadeIn-setup{
    opacity:0;
}
.fadeOut-setup{
    opacity:1;
}
.fadeIn-setup.fadeIn-start {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fadeOut-setup.fadeOut-start{
    opacity:0;
}
```

ngShow and Hide works well. But the animation is not triggered.

I have updated to Angular 1.1.5. I find from the angular [documents](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate), there has been a change of syntax for CSS

I have also tried the new syntax with the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your code to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the working example in 1.1.5 :

http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/CTfL8/

```
 <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle!</button>

  <div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="{show:'list-show', hide:'list-hide'}">On</div>
  <div class="box off" ng-hide="toggle" ng-animate="{hide:'list-hide', show:'list-show'}">Off</div>
```

Comment: Thnx. So ng-animate has to work along with TweenMax lib for css animation?  Or is it possible to do the same with just ng-animate and seen on nganimate examples?

Answer (score 0):

Loads of changes from 1.1.5 to 1.2. 
So moved my code into 1.2. Animation is much more streamlined.

followed [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) example for animation.

Sadly Angular documentation for animation is almost nil. [YearOfMoo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) has some good documentation on animation on latest Angular